# What is the proper way to introduce relative context to a question, answer, or comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

What is the proper way to introduce or expand relative context to a question, answer, or comment?

For example, A person asks for the best way to caulk the exterior of the pictured window sill.  A person gives an answer to the question (a sufficiently good answer).  I see that the window sill was constructed incorrectly.

While the question was specific and the answer was correct for the question, I wonder what would be the proper way for me to bring up the issue of the sill, which neither the questioner or respondent has acknowledged is a problem, too?

Would explaining why the sill is a problem (and how to fix it) be an "Answer", a "Comment" to the question, or a "Comment" to the answer?

[Edit: Note, my inquiry is more to ask, "How to expand the initial scope of any question, answer, or comment by asking about or mentioning its context?"]

[2nd Edit (27.11.16): Okay, thanks.  I think I'd feel most comfortable doing a bit of both your suggestions:

1) Edit the original question with an endnote that there may be an exception (in which the given answer wouldn't work/be best) or an issue being overlooked,

2) Answer the question (if it hasn't been, yet) with a note about a possible exception or overlooked issue,

3) open a new question (without waiting to see if the exception or overlooked issue takes on a life of its own)

I consider this question resolved, thank you for your feedback.]

Answer (score 2):

In your situation I post a comment to the question indicating there are other issues that they didn't ask about. If they seek further details, that's a good time to direct them to ask a new question.

If I'm the person posting the answer to the question, I frequently append side notes and added advice to the end of my answer. The answer itself should always cover what the OP has asked, but adding another paragraph or two to the end for these further details helps the OP. Again, if comments start to shift to discussing these other issues, I'd recommend to the OP that they open a new question for the other issues they are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Given SE's design, the Right Answer would be to start a new Question using the same picture.

Comment: What would alert others to know the original question may be overlooking a problem not identified by either the original question or the answer?

Comment: Answer the question asked, point out the issue and say you are opening a new Question to discuss it. Remember, part of SE's intent is to come up on websearch for the question, and an answer in the wrong place is less likely to be found by those who need it.